# Sum property of element which have the same other properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with a lot of elements. Each element is like:

`e1 = {
    data: 12345,
    month: 8,
    year: 2018
}`

And with this array I want to create a new array of elements of the same type but with the sum of each data of the element which have the same month and the same year.

For example:
If my array is:

```
myArray = [
    {
        data: 1,
        month: 7,
        year: 2018
    },
    {
        data: 2,
        month: 8,
        year: 2018
    },
    {
        data: 3,
        month: 8,
        year: 2018
    }
]
```

I want this new array:

```
myNewArray = [
    {
        data: 1,
        month: 7,
        year: 2018
    },
    {
        data: 5,
        month: 8,
        year: 2018
    }
]
```

Could you help me with that by using javascript function ?

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: This should help your effort: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to index elements by month and year and increment `data` as you find new elements:

```js
var myArray = [{
    data: 1,
    month: 7,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    data: 2,
    month: 8,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    data: 3,
    month: 8,
    year: 2018
  }
];

var grouped = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  var key = `${curr.year},${curr.month}`;
  if (!(key in acc)) acc[key] = Object.assign({}, curr);
  else acc[key].data += curr.data;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(grouped));
```

Comment: That's gotta be the most unreadable javascript snippet i've ever seen. Please consider using semantic name for variable and parameters

Comment: @JorelAmthor `acc` and `curr` are standard names for the arguments for the `reduce` callback: It's even in the official doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Description

Comment: @slider -  I'll come to your defense that `acc`/`curr` are fine var names to use, but please note that, while extremely useful, MDN is not the "official doc"-- Mozilla doesn't somehow own JavaScript.